ng build hangs & stuck without error or warning, Angular 17
I'm using Angular 17.3.0 and node 22. This happens even from the default project initiated from angular cli. Angular cli build hangs without any error messages. From console, I'm seeing
ng build

[91m- Building...

Here are console logs after turning on verbose logging. Although it says done in the end, the process does not exit and just hang.
ng build --verbose

[91m- Building...

[0m[91m
  polyfills-RT5I6R6G.js  33.1kb

⚡ Done in 26ms
[0m[91m
  polyfills.server.mjs  261.7kb

⚡ Done in 48ms
[0m[91m
  chunk-QLJ3LW34.mjs       545.4kb
  main.server.mjs           42.4kb
  chunk-DMHSCYU6.mjs        11.8kb
  chunk-HQUS2UUF.mjs         2.0kb
  render-utils.server.mjs    1.4kb

⚡ Done in 4021ms
[0m[91m
  main-IE66FLJS.js  272.8kb

⚡ Done in 4226ms


Beware that Angular v17 doesn't support Node v22: https://angular.dev/reference/versions#actively-supported-versions as it didn't exist at that point in time AFAIK

@davidlj95 Having the same issue on node 20. When this happens (every now and again) the only way out is to kill all node processes through the task manager

Are you perhaps running this command in vscode's terminal when this happens?

@Pieterjan My local is on node 20.9.0 (windows) and it works with angular 17. My docker build previously uses 22.1 and that's what failed. I think the minor version still matters but upgrading to node 22.4 fixes both problems. Have you tried that?

As mentioned by David, Angular 17 does not support node 22 since it came out earlier than node 22. However, although Angular 17 still does not "officially" support node 22, there is a workaround & fix for them to work together.
As discussed here, the problem really happens around node version 22.1 - 22.2 and is later "fixed" by 22.4. So if you want them to work together, make sure you update node to above 22.4.
In my case, I used docker image node:22-alpine3.18 where it does not work and this is fixed by upgrading tonode:22-alpine3.19
